# How does LAPACKE_sgetrf work?

Tags: lapack

I just started with lapack. I thought let's start with LU decomposition, of the following matrix A:

```
1 1 0 3
2 1 -1 1
3 -1 -1 2
-1 2 3 -1
```

I wrote the follwinng program,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <lapacke/lapacke.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  float a[4][4]={
{1,1,0,3},
{2,1,-1,1},
{3,-1,-1,2},
{-1,2,3,-1}
};
  lapack_int m=4,n=4,lda=4,info;
  int i,j;
  lapack_int*ipiv=(lapack_int*)malloc(4*4*sizeof(lapack_int));

   m = 4;
   n = 4;
   lda = 4;

   info= LAPACKE_sgetrf(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR,m,n,*a,lda,ipiv);

   for(i=0;i<m;i++)
   {
      for(j=0;j<n;j++)
      {
         printf("%lf ",a[i][j]);
      }
      printf("\n");
   }
   return(info);
}
```

This should give

L=

```
1 0 0 0
2 1 0 0
3 4 1 0
-1 3 0 1
```

and U=

```
1 1 0 3
0 -1 -1 -5
0 0 3 13
0 0 0 -13
```

But in the docs I read that L en U are returned in A. How? Maybe skip the 1's on the diagonal of L en merge the two. Is that true?

I do

```
$ gcc -Wall  sgetrf.c -llapacke -llapack
```

I see a=
3.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000 2.000000 
0.666667 1.666667 -0.333333 -0.333333 
-0.333333 1.000000 3.000000 0.000000 
0.333333 0.800000 0.200000 2.600000

I does not make sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is perfectly correct and `LAPACKE_sgetrf` actually return an LU factorization of the matrix with partial pivoting. It returned :

```
3     -1   -1     2
2/3   5/3 -1/3  -1/3
-1/3   1    3     0
1/3   0.8  0.2   2.6
```

The L matrix is:

```
1       0    0    0
2/3    1   -1/3  -1/3
-1/3   1    1     0
1/3   0.8  0.2    1
```

The U matrix is:

```
3     -1   -1     2
0     5/3 -1/3  -1/3
0     0     3     0
0     0     0    2.6
```

The product is similar to A except for the permutation of the rows:

```
3  -1  -1  2
2   1  -1  1
-1   2   3 -1
1   1   0  3
```

The LU factorization you provided is correct (except for the last line of L, which must be -1 -3 0 1 instead of -1 3 0 1). But such a LU factorization is not always possible (See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition)). This is the reason why LAPACK compute a PLU factorization, where P is a permutation matrix, returned in `ipiv`. Indeed, such a factorization is always possible.

Comment: You are right about -1 -3 0 1. Now I understand that lapack gives another P*L*U then I did by hand. Last sunday I found out how get L and U out of the resulting a. It is how you explained me. It is not documented (as far as I can see). Also the P, 3 2 4 4 , must be read as (13)(34)=(134). So you must read from right to left. This is also not documented, I think.  Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome ! Exactly, the perbutation must be performed from right to left to transform LU into A. The most common use of LU factorization is solving Ax=b. It boils down to solving LUx=P^{-1}b. In this case, the swapping of the rows of b are performed from left to right.